# Is Logic Apps performance slower compared to a direct .NET REST Call?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I use ASP.NET 4.7 MVC 5 on an Azure App Service.

I currently get JSON response data by calling REST APIs directly from my .NET code and then deserialising this JSON using

```
var order = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Order>(json.ToString());
```

This works fine and is pretty good regarding speed. However I am now looking into Azure Logic Apps to see if this could be used to call 3rd party APIs which would then transform its native schema to my standard schema.

Would the use of Logic Apps slow down the retrieval of data from the API endpoints compared to my current native .NET approach. I have a feeling that it will as it may be much more asynchronous/fire and forget. I am hoping that I would just call into the Logic App and get the same response as if I had done it natively, but with greater flexibility and scalability.

Thanks.

EDIT: My question is about the use of Logic App versus native calling. So assume one job each. I confused the matter talking about transformation as well. Apologies

Comment: You're asking if two calls will be slower than one?

Comment: Sorry, my question was more about the use of Logic Apps to call an API endpoint versus a native call. So assume one job each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easy answer is yes. The api call in your native code would be fired immediately and return the payload to your application directly, whereas a logic app step has all the plumbing required by activity orchestration and infrastructure costs. You could probably measure a difference, but it may not impact the quality of your application, depending on what it is trying to do.

The question I would ask is “does it matter”? What are you giving up by using logic apps over c# code? Is it worth the trade off to enjoy the benefits of serverless computing (scale out, no infrastructure to maintain, focus on the what instead of the how, etc)?

Comment: Josh, great answer. I agree with the Logic App benefits. I was just a little worried how it would provide my lookup data in my Web App which needs to be pretty quick otherwise the user is waiting. So the call out to the Logic App would be synchronous I guess waiting for the response. I totally get the power of them. I was just hoping that they are appropriate for my use case and therefore can  replace my native C# calls.

Comment: Yeah I think logic apps should be viewed as an abstraction of a multi-step flow rather than a replacement for web api or api management. You would probably use a logic app to get shipping costs from a ups api and logic apps to submit a shipping request and track its status over time. I don’t see logic apps as something that you’d want your customers to interact with directly, even if it’s via an http trigger. Keep in mind that logic app triggers have sas tokens which you’d want to keep away from bad actors who could flood your back end with nonsense invocations

Comment: Thanks for this. My users would still access my web app's Action which would then call into the service layer project which would then call into the logic app instead of doing it locally. Am just exploring 3rd Party integration Engines for quick integration/transformation of 3rd party data, and with Azure, Logic Apps seems to be the first port of call. Mulesoft Anypoint is a leading non MS example of what I am looking to do, but I think Logic Apps can do this for more and more.