# Azure Logic App and Function App performance difference

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

We are in the process of setting up new project. Our requirements is to invoke multiple rest API's and aggregate the response and send it back to mobile client.

We are exploring these 2 options for our experience layer(Integration )
1. Logic Apps
2. Azure Function

We have observed one major difference with respect to performance between these two.

We run through simple use case to compare the performance.

we are just invoking a rest API to get some metrics with different options available

1. Just integrate with APIM as back-end service
2. Using Azure Function
3. Using Logic Apps

Below are the metrics
[image]

Logic app is taking longer time for execution compare to other options. Below is the simple logic app to invoke rest api

```
{
"definition": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "actions": {
        "GetReferenceData": {
            "inputs": {
                "headers": {
                    "Authorization": "@variables('AuthToken')"
                },
                "method": "GET",
                "uri": "url"
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_AuthToken": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Http"
        },
        "Initialize_AuthToken": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "AuthToken",
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "@{triggerOutputs()['headers']?['Access-Token']}"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {},
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "Response": {
            "inputs": {
                "body": "@body('GetReferenceData')",
                "statusCode": "@outputs('GetReferenceData')['statusCode']"
            },
            "kind": "Http",
            "runAfter": {
                "GetReferenceData": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Response"
        },
        "Response_2": {
            "inputs": {
                "body": "@body('GetReferenceData')",
                "statusCode": "@outputs('GetReferenceData')['statusCode']"
            },
            "kind": "Http",
            "runAfter": {
                "GetReferenceData": [
                    "Failed",
                    "Skipped",
                    "TimedOut"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Response"
        }
    },
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "outputs": {},
    "parameters": {
        "storageLocation": {
            "defaultValue": [],
            "type": "Array"
        }
    },
    "triggers": {
        "manual": {
            "inputs": {
                "method": "GET",
                "relativePath": "/referenceData",
                "schema": {}
            },
            "kind": "Http",
            "type": "Request"
        }
    }
},
"parameters": {}
}
```

We have so many use cases where we need to invoke the multiple rest API's and aggregate the result. With the above numbers it seems Function App is doing a way better job than Function App.For parallel operations i may rely upon durable functions over Logic apps.

So i just want to understand **why logic app is taking longer time almost double time compared to function for the similar operation?**

**Is logic app is not meant for these operations?**

Comment: I do not see much difference  between the timings between logic apps and sure function it is just few hundred millisecond,  what kind of load and system are you planning to integrate?give us some idea so we can suggest somethings

Comment: both approaches have cold starts. You can get better results if you use Premium plan for Azure Functions. PS: take a look on Durable Functions (Fan-in and Fan-out Pattern). It will make your life easier.

Comment: we started of with logic apps because of its capabilities(Easy integration, out of box exception handling, retry etc...). But when we do the same operations with functions we see better performance. Of course milliseconds also does matter. if we start using  more and more API's it may multiple.i assume the Logic app results due to by its design

Answer (score 1):

Refer another thread where this question is already answered. [Is Logic Apps performance slower compared to a direct .NET REST Call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52750349/is-logic-apps-performance-slower-compared-to-a-direct-net-rest-call/52750514)

Following addition may provide more insight

“Azure Functions is **code** being triggered by an event, whereas Logic Apps is a separate framework of **workflow** triggered by an event.”
The Logic App is a logical container for one workflow you can define using triggers and actions.

**A Logic App runs on a set of infrastructure of an Azure region (VM’s in a data centre), and it consists of several components not visible to you as it is abstracted away. By provisioning a Logic App, you leverage a bit of that infrastructure (indirectly via the Logic App Service) once you define a workflow and the flow gets triggered.**

Azure Functions are part of the Azure Web + Mobile suite of App Services and are designed to enable the creation of small pieces of meaningful, reusable methods, easily shared across services.

Comment: When we think about logic app infrastructure and abilities, the difference does make sense. ,But I don’t see logic apps as something that you’d want your customers to interact with directly, even if it’s via an http trigger.

Comment: we are using Durable functions for all the orchestration and workflow need. it is easy to manage with custom code as compared to Logic APP where we need to depend on their connector offering's . Also Microsoft is investing on Function APP you can deploy Function APP on prem with Kubernetes and Keda.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/enterprise-integration/basic-enterprise-integration) in the Azure Architecture Center may point you in the right direction:

> Logic Apps works best in scenarios that don't require low latency for a response, such as asynchronous or semi long-running API calls. If low latency is required, for example in a call that blocks a user interface, use a different technology. For example, use Azure Functions or a web API deployed to Azure App Service.

So if the mobile app will be blocked waiting for a response, choose Functions.

Now that this is all clear, let's complicate it back: there are both [stateful and stateless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/single-tenant-overview-compare#stateful-and-stateless-workflows) logic app workflows, and the stateless ones are faster.

Then, as your aim is to "invoke multiple rest API's", the toll of the Logic Apps may increase due to a more complex workflow.

Probably best to return to the testing board. :) I'd appreciate some new numbers.