# Azure Logic Apps performance

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I'm currently looking into Azure Logic Apps and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the documentation to get a feel for the kind of performance I can expect.  I'm also having some trouble finding articles/blog posts detailing any real-world examples using logic apps and the performance being experienced.

The scenario I'm trying to solve has the following flow:

1. Http Request triggers the logic app
2. The body of the request is saved to storage ... either Cosmos or Table Storage
3. Depending on some values in the request body, call a external API without caring about the response (fire and forget)
4. Respond to the original Http Request with an appropriate response (e.g. 200 OK if steps 2 and 3 succeeded)

... and all of this needs to happen under 1 second.  I'm not really sure what to expect in terms of number of requests per second coming into my flow, but I'm going to assume 100 requests per second.

I'm wondering if anyone has some real-world experience with logic apps, that might be doing something similar to what I'm looking at, and the performance they are experiencing?  Is what I've outlined above feasible?  Is there room for a higher number of requests per second?

I've considered Azure Functions (possibly Durable functions) but I'm not only concerned about the performance, but also the cold-start scenario, because I need my solution to work in real-time.  At the moment I'm just building a .NET Core API to encapsulate this flow (plus more), but I'm thinking an Azure Logic App could streamline what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

Overall LogicApps is a little bit slower, which can be a reason in your case you would not want to use it. To avoid cold starts in Functions you can use a premium plan with warm-up instances.

Also, read this threads:

- [Azure Logic App and Function App performance difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61101593/azure-logic-app-and-function-app-performance-difference)
- [Is Logic Apps performance slower compared to a direct .NET REST Call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52750349/is-logic-apps-performance-slower-compared-to-a-direct-net-rest-call/52750514)

Comment: Thanks for the links.  After further reading I'm beginning to agree with you that Logic Apps might not be the solution to go for if speed is what I require.  I thought about the premium plan option for Azure Functions to avoid cold-starts, but for the cost I feel I may as well build a .NET Core Web API and host it on a linux app service or Kubernetes cluster.  Once I start to get into those price ranges, I'm not sure what advantage a Azure Function would have over a standard .NET Core Web API?

Comment: If costs are almost the same, choose whatever suits your architecture better. The azure function is event-driven, which gives a lot of possibilities to easily create integration patterns, because of its wide range of bindings and triggers. But if you will use an HTTP, and want to use premium, the advantages of Azure Functions are getting blurry.